# Why this set is not a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V =\Bbb R^2$ and define addition and scalar multiplication operation as follows :

$u=(u_1, u_2)$
$v=(v_1, v_2)$

$$u+v=(u_1+v_1,u_2+v_2)$$

$$ku=(u_1k,0)$$

The book says : "the addition operation is the standard one from $\Bbb R^2$, but the scalar multiplication is not".
Why not ? For example :

$K=1$ and $u=(2,4)$ then $Ku=(2,0) \in V$
So what is the problem ??

Comment: Have you looked at the rest of the axioms for a vector space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scalar operation is not the usual one since that one is $k \cdot (a,b) = (ka,kb)$.

The problem with this definition of scalar multiplication is that $1 \cdot u \neq u$. In fact, we have $1 \cdot (u_1, u_2) = (u_1, 0)$.

Do you see why this is a problem?

Comment: I got it thanks!